# Check if multiple elements with same class exist

Tags: jquery

Wonder if there's any way to check if elements with the same class exists in a document.

For example:

```
<div class="panel">panel 1</div>
<div class="panel">panel 2</div>
<div class="panel">panel 3</div>
```

JS:

```
if ( $('.panel')[0] ) {
    console.log('exists')
}
```

.. but I want to check if MORE THAN ONE `panel` element exists, alteast 2.

Comment: `$('.panel').length > 1`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to use the `length` property to accomplish your task,

```
if($('.panel').length > 1) {
  console.log('yes, more than one element exist')
}
```

Comment: Thats what I meant, it would return true even if just one `.panel` exists, I want to check if multiple element with the same class exists

Comment: @Nimbuz now it'l do the job for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( $('.panel').length >= 2 ) {
    console.log('exists')
}
```

This should work

Comment: oh yeah, I wrote this very quickly - still didn't get the cake! Thanks anyway, I won't edit the answer so people see what you meant.

Comment: @Fonzy Sorry, but some of the future referrers might not have patience to view the comments.

Comment: np mate, just learning how to get around here. TIL ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the the length property ;)

```
if ($('.panel').length > 0) {
  // your code
}
```